# How to make an installer EXE/MSI file (for php files)

Tags: php, installation

Well I have two php files

```
db_config.php
index.php
```

with certain code.

**To do**

- I want to make an installer file, which should zip these two php files in an exe or msi file.
- and whenever user execute my installer file, it should extract my files to the specified folder on the pc.
- also it should look like user is installing an software solution, i.e it should have some instruction, next button, back button, cancel button and a browse button to specify the installation location. (as you have experienced during a normal software installation )

Regards

Qadir Hussain

Comment: What if the user doesn't have PHP installed on their Windows PC?

Comment: rather zip it, write a small application scanning for htdocs (or better httpconf and the root-) folder on hdd and offering user those available destinations. Then simply unzip into that folder/name

Comment: @Mark Baker it doesn't matter

Comment: @Qadir - why doesn't it matter? How is the user going to run your script if they don't have PHP?

Comment: What if they don't have a computer?

Comment: @Mark Baker acctully  I m making an plug in for OrangeHRM, in which a user can mark his/her attendance via QR code scan via Android. If any one is installing my plug it must have OrangeHRM and to Run the OrangeHRM it is highly recommeded that you must have php xammp or wamp etc, so if some body have not installed the OrangeHMR he/she would not install my installer file. Hope the answer of question :)

Comment: Simply providing a zip is by far the easiest answer... as OrangeHRM isn't purely for Windows, then a Windows exe or MSI is rather limiting; and you can't guarantee that the Windows PC will have PHP installed if they're running the OrangeHRM as Saas

Comment: @Mark Barker what about the David Houde's answer down there? have you tied this

Comment: I see his answer, which directly answers your question, but is still Windows-specific

Comment: @MarkBaker so what you recommend what should i do, first I must check that either php is installed or not and what if the user is installing my installer on linux based OS,as exe/msi are not supported by the linux based OS?

Comment: I would recommend his original suggestion of simply creating a .zip file. The reason being that many people have their installations in custom locations, many people are inherently afraif of .exe/.msi as they can potentially be virus (php is a text file, why should i download a text file that is .exe, etc), and your package only includes a small number of files which would make this way fairly easy. If you are looking for seperate installers for each OS, it is also relatively simple if you insist on that route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) is a great Open Source tool for installing software. From the website:

> NSIS (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System) is a professional open
>   source system to create Windows installers. It is designed to be as
>   small and flexible as possible and is therefore very suitable for
>   internet distribution.
>
> ...
>
> NSIS is script-based and allows you to create the logic to handle even
>   the most complex installation tasks. Many plug-ins and scripts are
>   already available: you can create web installers, communicate with
>   Windows and other software components, install or update shared
>   components and more.